# Theos: How to hook a method with a block argument? (CDUnknownBlockType)

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos, tweak, logos

```
%hook HTTPClient
- (CDUnknownBlockType)completionForSuccess:(CDUnknownBlockType)arg1 {
}
%end
```

I am wondering what to place in place of `CDUnknownBlockType` here (generated from class-dump). I do not know the arguments to the block so I cannot put the exact signature. Is it possible to instead use `MSHookMessage` with a generic pointer as the argument? A generic `void *` pointer did not work for me here as the message does not match.

Is there a way to get the block's signature?

Answer (score 5):

You can replace the `CDUnknownBlockType` with `id`.
It's as simple as that.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!